# rescale ubuntu terminal window size

Tags: command-line

I have just created a new Ubuntu terminal only virtual environment.  As you can see below then I maximise the terminal window the terminal does not increase in size (giving me more space to see what I'm working on) there is just alot of grey space betwen the window frame and the terminal.

[image: ubantu terminal window size]

When I look at Veiw>VirtualScreen1, the resizing options are not available to me. 
[image]

Could someone let me know how to get the terminal to maximise to the edge of the window frame please?

Comment: i would ssh to the host...

Comment: thanks cmak.fr, but i have no idea how I would do that

Comment: @Stacey https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906441/how-to-ssh-to-a-virtualbox-guest-externally-through-a-host